# ElasticSearch: [multi_match] query does not support [search_analyzer]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

In ElasticSearch 7.x, I've indexed the data fields with an analyzer that has a [synonym filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).
However, to support boosting the queries that "exactly" match query terms in the data fields over the ones matched with their synonyms in the data, I'm going to use [`search_analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html).

To this end, for the query that I want to match exactly, I want to provide an analyzer that does not have a synonym filter in it. This can be done by the `search_analyzer`. However, my major query is a [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query to search these terms on all the desired fields (and with different importance (boosting)).

It seems that ElasticSearch does not allow `search_analyzer` in the `multi-match` query.
What are the alternatives? either for my high-level solution (to boost exact words over their synonyms) or to incorporate `search_analyzer` when I'm searching in different fields with different boosting (importance weight).

PS: I do not want to re-index the data fields one with a synonym analyzer and another without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Search_analyzer` is the [param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) for *index time*, so if you want to set it for the field with synonym:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                        "filter" : ["synonym"]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer": "synonym",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "content" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer": "synonym",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
}
```

In this way you have set the default analyzer for query time. So you now could perform a `multimatch` query in this way:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "bread cereal",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields": [
        "description",
        "content"
      ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```

If you haven't set a specific `search_analyzer` at index time for those field the same analyzer used to indicize is used at query time. If you haven't set a `search_analyzer` on index time, you could [force to use a specific analyzer at query time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/specify-analyzer.html#specify-search-query-analyzer) putting `analyzer` param in query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "bread cereal",
      "analyzer" : "standard",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields": [
        "description",
        "content"
      ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```